# How to set up a communication between 2 node.js microservices in an Azure service fabric?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-service-fabric

I am planning to set up an Azure service fabric, and wondering how to set one service to send some data to another microservice. I have one .net core microservice and many node microservices. If I am using guest executable to set up my node services, is there any way to communicate between those services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [specify endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app#update-endpoints-and-register-with-naming-service-for-communication) for your guest executables:

> Furthermore you can ask Service Fabric to publish this endpoint to the
>   Naming Service so other services can discover the endpoint address to
>   this service. This enables you to be able to communicate between
>   services that are guest executables. The published endpoint address is
>   of the form UriScheme://IPAddressOrFQDN:Port/PathSuffix. UriScheme and
>   PathSuffix are optional attributes. IPAddressOrFQDN is the IP address
>   or fully qualified domain name of the node this executable gets placed
>   on, and it is calculated for you.

E.g. in your `ServiceManifest.xml` you can configure the `Endpoints` section:

```
<Endpoints>
    <Endpoint Name="NodeAppTypeEndpoint" Protocol="http" Port="3000" Type="Input" />
</Endpoints>
```

Using this, you can map the guest executable service endpoint to the same port that your node service listens on.  Ensure that each node service listens on a unique port.

The same `Endpoints` configuration section applies to your .net stateless service `ServiceManifest.xml`.

Now that you have an address for each service, you can communicate using clients appropriate to the target service RPC framework.